# searchbar filter results from display but not from the rest of the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data throw searchbar but the problem is that only fetch from the display result, it ignores completely the rest of the information. I'm aware that I'm doing a splice to show me only the first 8 results but as soon as I start writing on the searchbar it filters only between those 8. I'm pretty sure I am missing a step but don't know how to search a solution for that either.

I share some of my code:

````
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './navbar.css'
import Cardlist from '../body/CardList';


function SearchBar(){
 const [characters, setCharacters] = React.useState([]);
 const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');
 const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
 const [error, setError] = React.useState(); 



 React.useEffect(()=>{
  const API_PUB = process.env.REACT_APP_API_PUB_KEY;
  const ts = 1;
  const hash = '(not display)';
  const URL_KEY = `https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=${ts}&apikey=${API_PUB}&hash=${hash}`;
  
 axios.get(URL_KEY)
  .then(characters=>
    {setCharacters(characters.data.data.results.slice(0,8));
  })
  .catch((err)=>
  {setError(err);})
  .finally(()=>
  {setLoading(false);});
},[])

const charactersArray = Object.values(characters)
console.log(charactersArray)
if (loading) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}

if (error || !Array.isArray(charactersArray)) {
  return <p>There was an error loading your data!</p>;
}
const characterSearch = search

const filterCharacters = search.length === 0 ? charactersArray : 
 charactersArray.filter((character => character.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
/*   handleChange = (e) =>{
  this.setState({searchField:e.target.value})
  } */
 
  return (
    <div className="containerGalery">
      <nav className="barra"> 
            <div className="logo"/>
            <div className="barraSeparadora">|</div> 
            <div className="lupa" alt="lupa"/> 
            <input className="buscador"  
        type="text"
        placeholder="buscar"
        value={characterSearch}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
        </nav>
        
    <span>
    <Cardlist charactersArray={filterCharacters} fallback={"Loading..."}/>
    </span>
    </div>
  );

}

export default SearchBar;```

I try to express myself as clear as possible, english is not my native language, sorry if something is not completely clear.
````

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is that only fetch from the display result, it ignores completely the rest of the information.

The rest of the information is ignored because this line throws it away:

```js
setCharacters(characters.data.data.results.slice(0, 8));
```

The information within `characters.data.data.results` (the fetched data) will naturally go out of scope when that function ends. You should put into state anything and everything that your component needs from it.

Try setting the state something like:

```js
// Keep all the characters in component state.
setCharacters(characters.data.data.results);
```

and then change `filterCharacters` to:

```js
// If the user has typed something, show all matches (regardless of how many).
// Otherwise, show just the first 8.
const filterCharacters =
  search.length === 0
    ? charactersArray.slice(0, 8)
    : charactersArray.filter(character => character.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
```

The difference (with these changes) is that you move `.slice(0, 8)` to the point where you *render* the component (as opposed to where you set state). That then means you should be able to keep all the characters in your component's state, but also only show a selection of them to the user.

---

Side note: It seems strange to me that your component fetches the data just once (as opposed to re-fetching based on what the user has typed), but I'm not sure what your requirements are.

Currently, your `useEffect` has an empty dependency array as its second argument. This means the effect (which fetches and sets the `characters` as state) activates only *once* (when the component initially mounts).

Comment: Tried already changing slice and also removing slice and I applied limit the parameter in the URL  and it happens the same thing.